# Transposing a table while adding headers

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have a table like that :

```
FRANCE       PARIS
FRANCE       MARSEILLE
FRANCE       LYON
SPAIN        MADRID
SPAIN        BARCELONA
SWITZERLAND  ZURICH
SWITZERLAND  GENEVA
SWITZERLAND  BERN
```

Which I would like to transpose so it looks like this :

```
FRANCE       SPAIN       SWITZERLAND
PARIS        MADRID      ZURICH
MARSEILLE    BARCELONA   GENEVA
LYON                     BERN
```

If I had access to better suited tools I could do it in 5 minutes using loops, but I only have access to Excel at work (and VBA, which I don't know anything about).

What I've done so far is an ugly solution that works. Firstly I create a transition table, with COUNTIF and SUMPRODUCT, and then use VLOOKUP to create my final table.

Is there a more elegant way to achieve what I'm trying to do ?

Comment: FWIW this isn't a transposition, it's more like a form of pivoted aggregation/grouping. What version of Excel are you using and are you looking for an Excel-based solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can use "Remove Duplicates", then transpose the countries to a single row, you can use this array formula (entered with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>) under that:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$8=E$1,ROW($A$1:$A$8)-ROW(A$1)+1),ROWS(A$1:A1)))
```

[image]

Then, to hide the `#NUM` errors when it doesn't find any further matches, just wrap that formula in `=IFERROR([formula above],"")`.

Comment: You must be some kind of wizard, because this worked perfectly ! Me and another analyst tried to understand your formula but to no avail. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @ArnaudStephan - It's been a while since I found/started using similar formulas, but searching online for "excel index small if row" returns similar formulas, like [this one](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-nth-match-with-index-match) or [this one](https://www.exceltactics.com/make-filtered-list-sub-arrays-excel-using-small/4/) where they explain it a little more.

Answer (score 2):

With data in columns **A** and **B**, try this short VBA macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, N As Long
    Dim k As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(1, 3) = Cells(1, 1)
    Cells(2, 3) = Cells(1, 2)
    i = 3
    j = 3

    For k = 2 To N
        If Cells(k, 1) = Cells(k - 1, 1) Then
            Cells(j, i) = Cells(k, 2)
            j = j + 1
        Else
            i = i + 1
            Cells(1, i) = Cells(k, 1)
            Cells(2, i) = Cells(k, 2)
            j = 3
        End If
    Next k


End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to powerquery you can do the following (slightly inefficient but does the job).

Turn your data into a table called Table1 and go Data > From table (select your table) in Excel 2016/+. For 2013 use the powerquery tab after installing the add-in from Microsoft then perform the from table import. Open the editor window in the powerquery window and edit the M code to the following:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Country", type text}, {"City", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Country", "City"}, {{"Count", each _, type table}}),
    #"Expanded Count" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Count", {"Country", "City"}, {"Count.Country", "Count.City"}),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Expanded Count"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Transposed Table",{"Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column6", "Column8"}),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Columns", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"FRANCE", type text}, {"SPAIN", type text}, {"SWITZERLAND", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```